# "rails new" is not generating any of my project's folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

I have downloaded Ruby, and installed the rails gem, then I attempt to run `rails new my-project` and all I get is this:

```
c:\Projects>rails new my-project
  create
  create  README.md
  create  Rakefile
  create  .ruby-version
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
    run  git init from "."
```

When I open the `my-project` folder that rails created for me what I find in it is only:

```
.gitignore
.ruby-version
config.ru
Gemfile
Rakefile
README.md
```

and nothing else.

This is not what I got when testing this at home, and it's not what any guide says I should get. I have exactly zero folders generated by rails, it's nowhere near what I need to start development. I don't think I'm missing any installations. Here are the versions of ruby and of rails:

```
c:\Projects>ruby -v
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x64-mingw32]

c:\Projects>rails -v
Rails 6.0.2
```

IIRC I installed Ruby using the Windows Ruby Installer at rubyinstaller.org, the latest version with Devkit, then I simply ran `gem install rails` to get Rails.

The only thing I can think of is that my user does not have admin privileges in this computer, but when I try to Google if this is a requirement, all Google gives me is how to implement admin stuff in my app.

Comment: What does the folder structure look like under `my-project` after you ran `rails new my-project`?

Comment: Only .gitignore, .ruby-version, config.ru, Gemfile, Rakefile and README.md and nothing else.

Comment: That certainly seems abnormal. I don't think it's a `rails` or `ruby` tool version issue. Perhaps some kind of configuration issue somewhere. Perhaps you could give some background on how you installed the tools in your question (edit the question and provide the info from your comment as well as the tool info).

Comment: I used the ruby installer and then simply ran `gem install rails` to get Rails. I added this, as well as my previous comment, to the question. You think it can have something to do with user permissions for the OS?

Comment: I don't believe it's a permissions issue. I don't recall how I installed Ruby on my Windows 10 system. I have a `C:\Ruby25-x64` folder where all the Ruby goodies are. I just did a `gem install rails` and waited to make sure there were no errors on that install. Then did a `rails new foo` and it created all the expected application folders and files. The only thing I can think of off-hand is to ask if you're sure the `rails` gem installed without error, but that is a bit of a stab in the dark since I wouldn't expected it to "partially succeed" at creating a project.

Comment: Did your `rails new my-project` stop right after `run  git init from "."` with no error and return to the prompt? After `run  git init from "."` mine continues starting with `Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/MyName/Documents/Projects/foo/.git/` (I had done `rails new foo`). You didn't mention `.git` as one of the created folders, so it apparently died quietly trying to create it. Go to `my-project` and try the `git init` by hand and see if it has issues.

Comment: Yes, it stops without an error, however I do not have git installed in this machine, and so if I try to run `git init` by hand it says git is not a recognized command. I don't remember reading that git is required to have rails, but regardless, I'm probably going to install git and try again in a bit. Or maybe there is a way to skip using git altogether?

Comment: Yes, that's likely your issue then. I don't know off-hand how to create a project without `git`. You could try a quick google search on it and see if something useful turns up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try appending `--skip-git` to your `rails new` command. This will get you going in the short term.

Alternatively (and probably the better option in the long run), install `git`. The official Git documentation install instructions can be found here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue.  Thanks to Scott Schupbach answer I realize that I didn't Install git, because I was working in a fresh ubuntu 19.10 installation.

So for anyone with the same issue, just install git.

In Ubuntu (or other Debian-based Linux distribution) just type:

```
sudo apt install git
```

On Mac (using Homebrew):

```
brew install git
```

For Windows, non-Debian Linux systems, and alternative Mac installer options, see the official Git installation documentation: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

And that's all.

Best Regards!!

Comment: OMG, I wasted so much time trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

1. uninstall rails
2. delete the project folder
3. install git with sudo - "sudo apt install git"
4. reinstall rails - "gem install rails"
5. create the project folder again and do the cd command to be in the new folder
6. Run the command again- "rails new [project name]"

Comment: This is the nuclear option. I wouldn't recommend this approach unless you've exhausted all other options. For most people, step 3 alone will be sufficient. But just blindly doing all of this is kind of like trying to open a walnut with a sledge hammer.

Answer (score 0):

Facing this issue as git was not installed on system.

Try to run below command to install git

> sudo apt install git

And then create a new rails project with rails command

> rails new myApp

It will create complete folder structure for you