# rails new mytest doesn't create correct folder structure

Tags: structure, ruby-on-rails-6

I've just installed rails 6.0.2.1 with rvm
ruby version 2.6.3p62 ( using ruby-2.7.0-preview1 delivers the same result )

and the output is this:

```
rails new mytest
      create  
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
```

instead of rails 3.2.22( output summary ):

```
rails new mytest
  create  
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/images/rails.png
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/mailers
  create  app/models
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  config
  ...
     run  bundle install
```

any ideas? is just a bug or am I wrong?

Comment: It is not really clear to me what your issue is here. What would be the expected result? How does it differ from the result you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, the problem was simple no git installation on this machine

```
rails new mytest --skip-git
```

run as aspected!

Thank to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59363292/rails-new-is-not-generating-any-of-my-projects-folders)